# How to user drawer navigation and stack navigation for same screen?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation-stack

This is my react native app.js file code.

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const App = () => {
  return (
    
    <AuthProvider>
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthStack/> 
       {/* <DrawerNavigation/> */}
    </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthProvider>
  )
}
export default App;
```

In the `<AuthStack/>` I added the stack navigation. According to that code, it's working.
And also added `<DrawerNavigation/>` I created drawer navigation to the screen. But cannot use both in same code like abow. I am new to the react-native can you tell me how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar implementation I've made before and is working.

```js
const AppHomeTabs = createBottomTabNavigator()

function AppHomeTabsNavigator() {
  const { Screen, Navigator } = AppHomeTabs

  return (
    <Navigator>
      <Screen name="one" component={ScreenOneStack} />
      <Screen name="two" component={ScreenTwoStack} />
    </Navigator>
  )
}
```

and

```js
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()

function ScreenOneStack() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerType="slide"
      backBehavior="initialRoute"
    >
      <Drawer.Screen
         name="foo"
         component={ScreenFoo}
      />
      <Drawer.Screen
         name="bar"
         component={ScreenBar}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  )
}
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I know how I call to this both functions from app.js?

Comment: ```return <NavigationContainer>
      <AppHomeTabs />
    </NavigationContainer>
```